# How to connect in db2 LUW with SSL using python?

Tags: db2

I'M running SQL queries (client side) from DB2 databases using ibm_db & ibm_db_dbi using pandas. However one of our datasource implemented new security.I'm running Python3.7 and DB2 11.0

Below is my current connection string:

```
dsn = (
    "DRIVER={{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}};"
    "DATABASE={0};"
    "HOSTNAME={1};"
    "PORT={2};"
    "PROTOCOL=TCPIP;"
    "UID={3};"
    "PWD={4};"
    "Security={5};"
    "SSLClientKeystoredb={6};"
   "SSLClientKeystoreDBPassword={7};").format(dsn_database, dsn_hostname,      dsn_port, dsn_uid, dsn_pwd, dsn_security, dsn_keystore, dsn_keypwd)
```

And I have an error message:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 con= ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")

SQLCODE=-1109on: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1109N  The specified DLL "GSKit Error: 202" could not be loaded.  SQLSTATE=42724

I also look for GSKit and install it in my machine, then put it on the Path for environment variable but error still persists.

Hope you can help me with this problem.

Comment: GSKit rc=202 is inability to open a key file. [GSKit return codes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAL2T_8.1.0/com.ibm.cics.tx.doc/reference/r_gskit_error_codes.html). Do you specify full path to this file? Is it readable by the user running the application?

Comment: Hi @MarkBarinstein, sorry for the late reply, yes actually I have an application that connects to it, and it works perfectly fine. I'm just having challenges connecting to it using python with this library ibm_db.

Comment: Hi, just an update regarding this question, Finally I can connect to the datasource. So I have below the correct connection string.

    dsn = (
        "DRIVER={{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}};"
        "DATABASE={0};"
        "HOSTNAME={1};"
        "PORT={2};"
        "PROTOCOL=TCPIP;"
        "UID={3};"
        "PWD={4};"
        "SECURITY=ssl;"
        "sslTrustStoreLocation={6};"
        "sslTrustStorePassword={7};").format(dsn_database, dsn_hostname,  dsn_port, dsn_uid, dsn_pwd, dsn_security, sslTrustStoreLocation,sslTrustStorePassword)